# How do I drop rows in a Dataframe based on a string list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a string list in python.
I have a 5000 rows DataFrame.
I have 5 columns.

I want to delete rows by comparing values from an array in a column.

Comment: Please share an example of the data.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter rows based on conditions with pandas. Google is your friend for these sorts of questions but if I understand your question correctly you can

keep only rows in the list with.

```
keep = ['Asia','Africa', 'Americas', 'Europe']
continents[continent["name"].isin(keep)]
```

keep rows NOT in the list

```
remove = ['Asia','Africa', 'Americas', 'Europe']
continents[continent["name"].isin(remove) == False]
```

Consider the below as a mask.

```
mask = continent["name"].isin(keep)
```

which would return something like

```
print(mask) 

True  # this is in the keep list
True  # this is in the keep list
True  # this is in the keep list
False # this is NOT in the keep list
True # this is in the keep list
False # this is NOT in the keep list
```

When passed into the continents list it will only display the `True` values. Like so...

```
continents[mask]
```